# DataWeave flattened nested object

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

Hi I am trying to convert the below input to following output.

Input :

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "test": [
    {
      "key1": "value1"
    }
  ],
  "insuranceContractLayer": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "key1": "value1",
      "layerInfo": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test",
        "key1": "value1"
      },
      "otherKey": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test",
        "key1": "value1"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "key1": "value2",
      "layerInfo": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "test2",
        "key1": "value2"
      },
      "otherKey": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "test2",
        "key1": "value2"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is the expected output:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "test": [
    {
      "key1": "value1"
    }
  ],
  "insuranceContractLayer": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "key1": "value1",
      "layerInfo__id": 1,
      "layerInfo__name": "test",
      "layerInfo__key1": "value1",
      "otherKey__id": 1,
      "otherKey__name": "test",
      "otherKey__key1": "value1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "key1": "value2",
      "layerInfo__id": 2,
      "layerInfo__name": "test2",
      "layerInfo__key1": "value2",
      "otherKey__id": 2,
      "otherKey__name": "test2",
      "otherKey__key1": "value2"
    }
  ]
}
```

So what I want to achieve is whatever object is inside `insuranceContractLayer`. It will be flattened and its key will be `prefix +  "__" + originalKey`

I am hitting my head for past 8 hours and I am not able to understand its weird syntax.
Here is the code I tried :

```
%dw 2.0
import flatten from dw::core::Objects
output application/json
fun flattenObject(obj, prefix = "") =
    obj match {
        case is Object -> flatten(obj mapObject {
            (flattenObject($$, if (prefix == "") "" else prefix ++ "__" ++ ($$ as String))) : $
        })
        else -> {
            { (prefix): obj }
        }
    }
---
flattenObject(payload)
```

Here is the error :

> Invalid input "match {\n        case is Object -> flatten(obj
> mapObject {\n            (flattenObject($$, if (prefix == "") "" else
> prefix ++ "__" ++ ($$ as String))) : $\n        })\n        else ->
> {\n            {", expected Namespace (line 5, column 9):
>
> 5|     obj match {   |  ... 10|             { (prefix): obj }
>
> Location: main (line: 5, column:9)

I have tried many variations and it is still throwing errors. I am trying to run my code on https://dataweave.mulesoft.com/learn/dataweave

I even tried the simplest version

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload mapObject ((value, key, index) -> 
    if (key == "insuranceContractLayer") 
        value map ((layerValue, layerIndex) -> 
            {
                "id": layerValue.id,
                "key1": layerValue.key1,
                "layerInfo__id": layerValue.layerInfo.id,
                "layerInfo__name": layerValue.layerInfo.name,
                "layerInfo__key1": layerValue.layerInfo.key1,
                "otherKey__id": layerValue.otherKey.id,
                "otherKey__name": layerValue.otherKey.name,
                "otherKey__key1": layerValue.otherKey.key1
            }
        )
    else
        value
)
```

And it is throwing below error:

> Cannot coerce Number (1) to Object
>
> 4| payload mapObject ((value, key, index) ->    |  ... 19|
> value
>
> Trace:   at main::main (line: 4, column: 20)

But still it is throwing error and I have no clue what does it wants. I could have done this with Javascript easily but I need to do this in DataWeave only and I have no clue how to do this. Can someone help me here?

Comment: Please use code formatting for code, logs and errors, not quote formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last script would not have fully worked but should not give that error in my opinion. It is failing to map the value `1` using map(), which should only happen for the key `insuranceContractLayer`. Maybe is a bug in the playground. It would not have worked anyway because comparing a key with a String always returns false. You should have converted the key to String first (`key as String`).

If just want to map the values in the array without changing the rest of the object you can use the `update` operator, which is more readable and clear in the intention, then map the elements of the array.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload update {
    case a at .insuranceContractLayer -> 
            a map {
                "id": $.id,
                "key1": $.key1,
                "layerInfo__id": $.layerInfo.id,
                "layerInfo__name": $.layerInfo.name,
                "layerInfo__key1": $.layerInfo.key1,
                "otherKey__id": $.otherKey.id,
                "otherKey__name": $.otherKey.name,
                "otherKey__key1": $.otherKey.key1
            }
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "test": [
    {
      "key1": "value1"
    }
  ],
  "insuranceContractLayer": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "key1": "value1",
      "layerInfo__id": 1,
      "layerInfo__name": "test",
      "layerInfo__key1": "value1",
      "otherKey__id": 1,
      "otherKey__name": "test",
      "otherKey__key1": "value1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "key1": "value2",
      "layerInfo__id": 2,
      "layerInfo__name": "test2",
      "layerInfo__key1": "value2",
      "otherKey__id": 2,
      "otherKey__name": "test2",
      "otherKey__key1": "value2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I hope this will be helpfull

Input:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "test": [
    {
      "key1": "value1"
    }
  ],
  "insuranceContractLayer": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "key1": "value1",
      "layerInfo": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test",
        "key1": "value1"
      },
      "otherKey": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test",
        "key1": "value1"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "key1": "value2",
      "layerInfo": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "test2",
        "key1": "value2"
      },
      "otherKey": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "test2",
        "key1": "value2"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

DataWeave Script:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
  id: payload.id,
  test: payload.test,
  insuranceContractLayer: payload.insuranceContractLayer map ((layer, index) -> {
    ((layer - "layerInfo" - "otherKey") ++ 
    (("layerInfo" ++ "__id"): layer.layerInfo.id) ++ 
    (("layerInfo" ++ "__name"): layer.layerInfo.name) ++ 
    (("layerInfo" ++ "__key1"): layer.layerInfo.key1) ++
    (("otherKey" ++ "__id"): layer.otherKey.id) ++ 
    (("otherKey" ++ "__name"): layer.otherKey.name) ++ 
    (("otherKey" ++ "__key1"): layer.otherKey.key1))
  })
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "test": [
    {
      "key1": "value1"
    }
  ],
  "insuranceContractLayer": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "key1": "value1",
      "layerInfo__id": 1,
      "layerInfo__name": "test",
      "layerInfo__key1": "value1",
      "otherKey__id": 1,
      "otherKey__name": "test",
      "otherKey__key1": "value1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "key1": "value2",
      "layerInfo__id": 2,
      "layerInfo__name": "test2",
      "layerInfo__key1": "value2",
      "otherKey__id": 2,
      "otherKey__name": "test2",
      "otherKey__key1": "value2"
    }
  ]
}
```